# How to make sure link color is enforced even when text is colored

Tags: css, colors, hyperlink

I want to make sure links appear in a different color even when I color the text that contains them. Right now my links show up as a different color but only when the text is not colored. If the text on the page is colored, I just see a different colored underline when I hover over them. I want people to know that there are links there. Thanks!

Comment: Seeing the code would help get you an answer.

Comment: @Null is right, you should really post your code.

Comment: Written like this, your question has "Colour the links" as an answer. But that would be too simple, wouldn't it?

Comment: @user3308696, I went ahead and answered your question, but please note that in the future you should provide code examples in your questions and be as detailed as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stackoverflow! You can specify your link styles in their various states by using the `a:` selector in your CSS. The link style will not be affected by any other styling rules in your CSS, unless you define a more specific rule (such as `p a:link`, which would affect all of the links inside of the `<p>` tags. Please see the code and link below:

http://jsfiddle.net/xAQL5/1/

HTML:

```
<p>
Text,text,text,goose <a href="#">Link</a>
<p>
```

CSS:

```
p{
color:blue; /*Colors the paragraph text blue.*/
}

a:link{
color:black;  /*This will make the default color of your link black.*/
}

a:hover{
color:green; /*When a mouse hovers over the link it will turn green.*/
}

a:active{
color:red; /*This will cause the link to turn red when it is clicked.*/
}

a:visited{
color:orange; /*This will specify the color of the link after it has been visited.*/
}
```